# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, если между ними вводное

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> Актёрская карьера и семейная жизнь, на мой взгляд, понятия вообще
>   несовместимые.

Так хорошо?

Не:

*Актёрская карьера и семейная жизнь, на мой взгляд, – понятия вообще
несовместимые.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица, то тире не ставится, поэтому первый Ваш вариант верный:

**Актёрская карьера и семейная жизнь, на мой взгляд, понятия вообще несовместимые.**